# High CPU usage after Nvidia driver update in 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, cpu-load

I recently updated the OS on my Lenovo ThinkPad P51 from 20.04.3 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS.  Everything was working normally after the update, except that a particular graphics-heavy website wasn't working properly in Chrome (but was in FireFox).

While troubleshooting that issue, I updated the NVIDIA driver from nvidia-driver-390 to nvidia-driver-525.  This did get the site working in Chrome, but now I'm seeing much higher CPU usage, with spikes in both browsers to the point where the browsers and the computer itself are freezing and stuttering almost to the point of being completely unusable.

I've tried poking at some of the solutions people have posted online, but I'm honestly a bit out of my depth here.  I did try running "$ dkms status" based on a different solution and wound up with

> $ dkms status
>
> nvidia/525.60.11, 5.15.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)(WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

At this point I'm tempted to just roll back to 3.90 and call it good, but I'd like to get things working properly if possible.